# WIX Toolset Browse Dialog

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Does anyone here has an idea on how to hide removable hard drives on selecting custom directory path? I can't seem to find any documentation and I can't really find any related questions here.

Comment: I don't see USB stick drives in the list, but I do see a removable hard drive listed. I don't have time to debug this in detail right now, but there is a "Removable" flag for the volume and directory control. Setting it to "No" should logically solve the problem? Doing so is another story, it requires some setup and redefinition of the standard dialogs. [I found this "sample" on Github](https://github.com/dshorter/NGDev/blob/a39d208c5b4df5bb17d271fcef5098bd5eb82555/Utils/AUM/Setup/AUM.Setup/UI/ConfigurationDlg/Configuration.BackupsDrive.wxs).

Comment: I have a simpler sample here showing a custom dialog inserted into the WiX default dialogs: https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXCustomDialog - I hope these two hints can help you a little - all I can locate right now.

Comment: I have tried implementing a custom browse dialog and I added the removable property on the directory combo, it does nothing. Removable hard disk still shows. @SteinÅsmul

Comment: Source on github?